# Flutter ToggleButtons overflowing in AppBar actions

Tags: flutter, overflow, appbar

A rather wide ToggleButtons wrapped in SingleChildScrollView is overflowing in AppBar actions  but not in body. Is there a way to fix this?

Any suggestion appreciated!!

```
class _ToggleState extends State<Toggle> {
List<bool> selectList = [
10 items here
];
List<String> catList = [
10 items here
];

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('Title'),
      actions: [
        SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          child: ToggleButtons(
            children: catList.map((item) => Text(item)).toList(),
            isSelected: selectList,
          
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    body: Center(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        child: ToggleButtons(
          children: catList.map((item) => Text(item)).toList(),
          isSelected: selectList,   
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
}
```

Comment: can you wrap SingleChildScrollView of appbar with container and give it a width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to source code documentation

> **final List? actions;**
> This widget is stacked behind the toolbar and the tab bar. Its height will be the same as the app bar's overall height.
> Typically, these widgets are IconButton representing common operations. For less common operations, consider using a `PopupMenuButton` as the last action.

If you still wish to handle this case, we can use `LayoutBuilder` or `mediaQuery` to get size and handle the UI providing appBar elements width.

**Code snippet**

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) => Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: SizedBox(
            width: constraints.maxWidth * .2,
            child: Text('title'),
          ),
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          actions: [
            SizedBox(
              width: constraints.maxWidth * .8,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                child: ToggleButtons(
                  onPressed: (v) {
                    print(v);
                  },
                  direction: Axis.horizontal,
                  children: catList.map((item) => Text(item)).toList(),
                  isSelected: selectList,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
    /// ........
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That was quite informative. I do appreciate your help. All the best.